# store HTML object (div element) in raiseevent() method - pepper robo

Tags: javascript, python, html, pepper

in pepper robo tablet I have to display a webpage in webview on button click.

how can I store an object (html `div` element) in `raiseevent()` method

eg: `session.raiseevent("eventname", "htmldivelement")`

python function below to load url and webview

```
def web_view(self):

    url = "https://www.google.com"
    try:
        self.ts.loadUrl(url)
        self.ts.showWebview()
        #self.showWebview("https://www.google.com")
    except Exception, e:
        self.logger.info("Error while loading tablet: {}".format(e))
```

Comment: 1) Where is the button? On a html page on the tablet? Then to open a webpage on button click you can use simple javascript in html (<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';" value="Go to Google" />)
2) What have you tried to pass your div element? Why not as String? Where is the "htmldivelement" supposed to be processed? in Python code? in Javascript Code?
2)

Comment: button is on html page. when button is clicked on the pepper robot below function is called. function openWebPage() {
                alert('reached openWebPage');
                var displayView = document.getElementById("btnEPay")
                alert(displayView);
                ePayPage(displayView);
                //window.open("https://www.epay.com/");
           }

Comment: button is processed in javascript code and webview has to display from python code.

Comment: <div id="btnEPay" class="buttonstyle" onclick="openWebPage();"><center>pay by ePay</center></div>

Comment: 1) so you want to pass a div element from javascript to python code. 2) You want to "pass" the div element via raiseevent? 3) whats wrong with string? 4) what have you tried? 5) It would be helpful to understand your question if you add more code to your question

Comment: i want to pass div element via raiseevent()-- i tried to pass value as string and passed in raise event didnot call python function to display webview.<div id="btnEPay" value = "webView"class="buttonstyle" onclick="openWebPage();"><center>pay by ePay</center></div>

Comment: python code---- @qi.nobind
    def displaywebview(self):

        self.tts.say("inside web view function")
        url = "https://www.epay.com"
        try:
            self.ts.loadUrl(url)
            self.ts.showWebview()
            #self.showWebview("https://www.epay.com")
        except Exception, e:
            self.logger.info("Error while loading tablet: {}".format(e))

Comment: better add code to your question, code in comments is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't request to display arbitrary html on Pepper's tablet.

There are two ways you can update Pepper's tablet from Python:

- Load a new webpage with `ALTabletService.showWebview(url)`
- Have a webpage that is subscribed to an ALMemory event using the [javascript SDK](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/js/index.html), and raise almemory events with information about the new tablet state (these usually pass json, but could also send html any other format - in any way, you'll have to handle it in javascript). There are some examples of that in [robot-jumpstarter](https://github.com/aldebaran/robot-jumpstarter).